# Select Query incomplete

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have 17 records inserted in my table "book".

```
<?php
include 'config.php';

session_start();

$sql = "SELECT * from book";
$result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
$count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

if($count == 0){
    $error = "There is no books in the list";
}

?>
<html>
<body>

<table border="2" style="width:80%;" align="center">
<tr>
    <th>ISBN</th>
    <th>Title of the book</th>
    <th>Cost</th>
    <th>Copies</th>
    <th>Edition</th>
    <th>Publisher</th>
    <th>Copy Year</th>
    <th>Shelf Number</th>
    <th>Subject</th>

</tr>
<?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

$ISBN = $row['ISBN'];
$Title = $row['Title'];
$Cost = $row['Cost'];
$Copies = $row['Copies'];
$Edition = $row['Edition'];
$Publisher = $row['Publisher'];
$CopyYr = $row['CopyYr'];
$Shelf = $row['ShelfNo'];
$Subject = $row['SubName'];

?>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $ISBN; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $Title; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $Cost; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $Copies; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $Edition; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $Publisher; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $CopyYr; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $Shelf; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $Subject; ?></td>

</tr>

    <?php
}
?>
</table>
<br>
<table align="center" style="width: 30%">
    <tr>
<th><form action="AddBook.php" method="post">
        <input type="submit" value="Add Book"/>
    </form></th>
<th><form action="editbook.php" method="post">
        <input type="submit" value="Edit List"/>
    </form></th>
<th><form action="deletebook.php" method="post">
        <input type="submit" value="Delete Book/s"/>
    </form></th>
<th><form action="AdminSummary.php" method="post">
        <input type="submit" value="Back"/>
    </form></th>
    </tr>
</table>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

This will display 17 records in the table. But when I add another record to the table, It will display an incomplete record, a "500 server error", or an empty table.

I have been in the same problem for days, searching for a solution, and I can't find any.

I don't know what the problem is, so any help would be appreciated. Thank You :)

Comment: Can you throw us database dump here?

Comment: Could be web server config issue? every time you get 500 you need to check server logs first.

Comment: @JayminNoob how? I'm new here sorry btw :(

Edit: do you mean the list of SQL statements?

Comment: @meta how can I check the server log? I'm using PHP and XAMPP and I'm new to the environment. :(

Comment: @JayminNoob nvm, Its working now. Just some server error. Thank you for the time :)